# Connecting Instagram account to local account nodejs & Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, instagram

I'm trying to create a MEAN app that has local users but they will also be able to link their Instagram on to it (not log in using Instagram, rather just authorize the app to fetch their images).

Currently I'm using passport and jwt tokens to authenticate local users. I have a button that takes them to the instagram authentication page, then the app will authorize instagram successfully, and then be sent to the instagram redirect_uri on the server side, however this GET request has no information regarding which Local user was authenticating the instagram, so how can I assign that instagram access token to the local user who requested to link the account?

Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you.

edit:
I'm using npm instagram-node (https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-node) to assist with the api calls,

this is my instagram component typescript function that runs when the "Connect instagram" button is clicked

```
this.http.get('http://192.168.0.20:8080/auth/social/ig').subscribe(data => {
         window.location.href = data.url
     })
```

and this is what's in my app.js

```
//instagram
exports.authorize_user = function(req, res) {
res.redirect(api.get_authorization_url(redirect_uri, { scope: ['likes'], state: 'a state' }));
};

exports.handleauth = function(req, res) {
console.log('req user in handlauth');
console.log(req.user)
api.authorize_user(req.query.code, redirect_uri, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.body);
        res.send("Didn't work");
    } else {
        console.log('Yay! Access token is ' + result.access_token);
        res.send('You made it!!');
    }
});
};
```

^Ideally i'd want the token from the result there to be stored in the current user however req.user is null of course since this request had nothing to do with jwt tokens :/

```
//authorize isnta link
app.get('/auth/social/ig', exports.authorize_user);

// This is your redirect URI
app.get('/oauth/done', exports.handleauth);
```

Comment: Post the code along with the question that shows what you have done so far as it helps the community to understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering, what I ended up doing was in the authorize path
app.get('/auth/social/ig/:localuser', exports.authorize_user);

use a wildcard for the username and then put that the username in the state, then upon the callback from instagram just parse the state to get the local user username.